# Excel VBA - Add a date stamp to every other Column or Row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Basically its quite a simple thing (I think) but I can't seem to get it!

Essentially I am building a tracker and I need a date stamp put in whenever a cell is modified. I can put in the code so when anything in column b is modified to put a date in column C, but then I can't make it repeat for data put in column D to input a date in Column E.

Basically I would want a date stamp in every other Column. If it is easier to be every other row that would be fine as well I'll just change the titles around.

If its rows it would have to start from data in put in row 2 (headers), if its column data put in from column B (headers again).

Can anyone help? I've had a look online but can't seem to find the answer...

Comment: Show us what you have so far (code) so that we can improve it.

Comment: `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Count > 1 Then Set Target = Target.Cells(1, 1)
If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
    If Not IsEmpty(Target) Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now
    Else
        Target.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
    End If
End If
End Sub`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this event-based macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column Mod 2 = 0 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Offset(0,1) = Date
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This line is faulty:
`    If Target.Column % 2 = 0 Then`
Did you mean:
`    If Target.Column Mod 2 = 0 Then`

Comment: @Olly I didn't know that % doesn't work. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Worksheet_Change`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel)-Event (another good example for specific cells [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/213612/how-to-run-a-macro-when-certain-cells-change-in-excel)).

Depending on your needs you do something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Cells(1, Target.Column + 1).Value = Format(Now(), "dd.mm.yyyy")
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Its important to set `.EnableEvents = False` before inserting any values, otherwise it will fire the event again.